# Set Directive Angular after rendering view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to load my Angular Directive when my class change.

I have a directive who get the route and when this directive can get a route she set on a class in a div child.

But when the div child have the class, the directive don't run.

Route directive :

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('index', ['$rootScope','usersEntity', '$location', '$timeout',function($rootScope,usersEntity, $location, $timeout){
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'index',
    replace: true,
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $scope.user = function () {
            return usersEntity;
        };
        $scope.location = function () {
            return $location.path().replace('/', '');
        };
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event) {
            $scope.routeMap = {
                'login': 'users-log'
            };
            if ($scope.location().length < 1) {
                $scope.route = '';
            } else {
                $.each($scope.routeMap, function (index, value) {
                    if (index == $scope.location()) {
                            $scope.route = value;

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },
    link: function() {

    }
}
```

}]);

Thanks and sorry for my perfect English ;)